# Python access var() inside function

Tags: python, function, var

I have a dataframe defined earlier by this format

```
vars()['df_zscore_out1']=
```

I'm trying to access this dataframe inside a function and call this func()

```
def func():
  print(vars()['df_zscore_out1'])
func()
```

But got

```
KeyError: 'df_zscore_out1'
```

I tried passing it in the argument and it works

```
def func(df):
  print(df)
func(vars()['df_zscore_out1'])
```

Can anyone help to explain this? Thanks!

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars): "Without an argument, `vars()` acts like `locals()`."

Comment: "I have a dataframe defined earlier by this format `vars()['df_zscore_out1']=`" don't do this. Just stop dynamically creating variables. The problem is that in the global scope, `vars()` returns `globals()`, and in a local scope, it returns `locals()`. But you shouldn't be using any of these things, it's a bad design

Comment: Thanks for the advice. To simplify the question I didn't use actually name, which is supposed to be vars()['df_zscore_out%s' %i] and i is updating each loop. So, I created this dynamic variable along with others inside a for loop so that I can have couple of similar df after.   Is there any better ways to do so, if not creating variables dynamically using vars()?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

Since it isn't a local, it isn't accessible.

Just pass it in as an argument though. If a function needs data, parameters are how that data should be supplied unless you really need a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

When `vars()` is called without any arguments, it's equivalent to `locals()`, which only returns local variables. At the module level, `locals()` is equivalent to `globals()`.

So, when you call `vars()` outside of the function, you are essentially calling `globals()` and getting a list of global variables. When you call `vars()` inside `func()`, you are essentially calling `locals()` and getting the (empty) list of local variables in `func()`.

In order for `vars()` to be meaningful in this scenario, you'd need to pass the specific object you are trying to store variables in (i.e. a module, class, or instance).

Alternatively, you could call `globals()` directly instead of `vars()`.

Sources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: The global keyword would be of zero use here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sorry about that! I honestly have no idea where I saw `global` being referenced. Edited.